# Import Julia UnitRange to R using RCall

Tags: r, julia, rcall

I would like to import the Julia array including unit range below to R:

```
Any[1:6, 9, 12, 15]
```

What I exactly want is something equivalent to this in R:

```
c(1:6, 9, 12, 15)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
R"b <- $(collect(flatten(a)))"
```

Setup:

```
using Base.Iterators
a = [1:6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Testing

```
julia> R"b <- $(collect(flatten(a)))"
RObject{IntSxp}
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  9 12 15
```

Please also note that the Julian equivalent of `c(1:6, 9, 12, 15)` is:

```
julia> [1:6..., 9, 12, 15]
9-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  9
 12
 15
```